# Creating through model relation not creating relation

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

I'm trying to create a relation between models using Loopback, but for some reason it seems like it is not saving my relations at all. But it could also be that I'm doing something wrong.

The relation looks like this:

[image]

So a `User` can be in 0 or more `Pool`s. When they are in a `Pool` they are a `PoolMember`. And a `PoolMember` can add `Predictions`.

Right now I'm trying  to create a relation between a `User` and `Pool`s.

I did a `slc loopback:relation` and then selected `User` as **from** model. Then selected **hasMany** and picked `Pool` from the list. Then it asked if the relation has a **throughModel**. I selected **Yes** and then picked `PoolMember` from the list.

I'd then expect that either `PoolMember.json` or `Pool.json` has a relation defined in it. But they seem to remain unchanged.

I even deleted my project and redid everything. But have the same problem.

So am I doing something wrong here? Or is this a bug in Loopback?

Comment: Are you using embedded User model? Try to extend User model and then try to create relation between models.

Comment: @A.Z. That seemed to do the trick! Makes sense to extend the `User` object instead of using it directly. In case I want to add other properties in the future. But Loopback could've made it clear that you cannot use the `User` model as "through model". Anyway, could you please post that as an answer so I have something to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using built-in models ("User" in your case), you should extend built-in model and then create relation or any other modification.

> Currently you cannot modify a built-in model's required properties.  If you need to do this, then create your own custom model as a replacement instead.
>
> By default, a LoopBack application has a built-in User model defined by user.json (this file is part of the LoopBack framework.  **Don't modify it; rather, follow the procedure in Extending built-in models)**.

See [Customizing models](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Customizing+models) and [Managing users](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Managing+users)